# create image from gallery and create a folder

Tags: android

This simple code ask users to pick an image from gallery

```
  private void openGallery() {
      Intent gallery = 
         new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
         android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
      startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
         Uri imageUri = data.getData();
         imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
      }
   }
}
```

**My question** : I see many codes or apps creates a folder when a user upload an image. Should I do that ? and how to create a folder with the above code

Answer (score 2):

Check below code for create folder dynamically.

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString();
            new File(root + "/" + Constants.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + "/"
                    + Constants.SUB_DIRECTORY_NAME).mkdirs();
```

Please create bitmap file for your selected gallery image and save into your own created folder.

```
File outputfile = new File(root + "/"
                    + Constants.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + "/"
                    + Constants.SUB_DIRECTORY_NAME + "/", "img_"
                    + dateFormatter.format(new Date()).toString() + ".jpeg");

            OutputStream outStream = null;
            try {                   
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(outputfile);
                bmFrame.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, outStream);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());

            } finally {
                try {
                    if (outStream != null) {
                        outStream.flush();
                        outStream.close();
                        bmFrame.recycle();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
```

use above code in onActivityResult

```
@Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
         Uri imageUri = data.getData();
         imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);

         Bitmap bmFrame = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                    this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);

         //Add above code here.
      }
   }
```

Comment: thanks for your asnwer , but why do they create a folder ? like instagram when upload a photo a folder iscreated with the image, why? can we use that in our coding somehwere ?

Comment: @Moudiz I think instagram save an image into a local folder before uploading on a server. Please check my edited answer for save image into a local folder.

Comment: but why the save in locat folder ? what is the purpose ? and please I like your code, how to add your code in the above in onactivityresult (with my above question)

Comment: @Moudiz Please check edited answer with onActivityResult.

Comment: I am getting this error IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: @Moudiz Please use your directory name instead of Constants.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME